# Are positive integers of the form $p^2+p+1$ known to be special?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was plugging $s=3$ in the Riemann zeta function followed by factorization, when I encountered the term $p^2+p+1$ where $p$ is a prime. I was curious if this particular number has been studied before and if anything special is known about it. Thank you.

Comment: This is [A060800](http://oeis.org/A060800).  Nothing on that link looks terribly interesting, but maybe it's a start.

Comment: Such numbers, when multiplied by $p-1$, give $p^3-1$.

Comment: Norms of integers in $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ with $\omega^3=1$.

Comment: Thanks all for the interesting information and edits. It was useful to learn about the idea of norms since I did wonder if the sequence would have overrepresentation of primes as compared to a sequence of positive integers up to a given n and did find some paper about norms and primes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.00531

Comment: What did you "factorize" about $\zeta(3)$? I don't see the connection to $p^2+p+1$.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $n^2+n+1$ is a special case $(z,w)=(n,1)$ of $z^2+zw+w^2$ which definitely is well-studied.

---

Define a function $r:\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C$ by $$r(z,w)=r_1z^2+r_2zw+r_3w^2$$ such that $r_1,r_2,r_3\in\mathbb C$. This is called a *binary form of degree 2*.

For $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb C$, given the condition that $ad-bc=1$, we can substitute: $$z\mapsto az+cw$$ $$w\mapsto bz+dw$$

And this will yield another polynomial that has the same (or an *invariant*) form: $$r'(z,w)=r(az+cw,bz+dw)=r_1'z^2+r_2'zw+r_3'w^2$$

In other words: let $S=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \end{pmatrix}$ such that $\det S=1$. Left-multiplying $S$ by $(z\;\;\; w)$ yields: $$(z\;\;\; w)\times \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \end{pmatrix} = (az+cw\;\;\; bz+dw)$$ and so the substitution $(z,w)\mapsto (az+cw, bz+dw)$ is just a linear combination of the rows of $S$ with coefficients from the row vector $(z\;\;\; w)$.

Now a question is: are the coefficients $(r_1,r_2,r_3)$ and $(r_1',r_2',r_3')$ also related by matrix multiplication? The answer is: yes (but with column vectors)! In fact:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
r_1' \\
r_2' \\
r_3' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a^2 &ab &b^2 \\
ac &ad+bc &bd \\
c^2 &cd &d^2 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
r_1 \\
r_2 \\
r_3 \end{pmatrix}$$ And the coefficients elegantly satisfy a simple identity: $$r_2^2-4r_1r_3=(r_2')^2-4r_1'r_3'$$

---

So more generally, the expression $n^2+n+1$ can be given by $r(z,w)$ where $z=n$ and $w=1=r_1=r_2=r_3$. This whole concept (called *classical invariant theory*) is not unique to prime arguments though, but what is studied about the expression does contain this concept and I think it is still pretty special.

Comment: Thanks Mr Pie for the detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

The number $n^2+n$ is a [pronic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number) (also called an *oblong* or *rectangular* number); equivalently, these are twice a *triangular* number $T_n = n(n+1)/2$.

Fermat studied these numbers a great deal, included the special case you highlight where $n^2+n+1= 2T_n+1 = p$ is prime. In that circumstance, the composition of $T_n$ is connected with numbers which are the sum of two squares (something Fermat spent a great deal of time studying).

Comment: Thanks @ Kieran MacMillan for telling me about pronic numbers and Fermat's related work.